# Determine if points are within a rotated rectangle (standard Python 2.7 library only)

Tags: python-2.7, math, geometry, coordinates, jython-2.7

I have a rotated rectangle with these coordinates as vertices:

```
   1   670273   4879507
   2   677241   4859302
   3   670388   4856938
   4   663420   4877144
```

---

[image]

---

And I have points with these coordinates:

```
670831  4867989
675097  4869543
```

Using only the Python 2.7 standard library, I want to determine if the points fall within the rotated rectangle.

- I am not able to add additional Python libraries to my Jython implementation

---

What would it take to do this?

Comment: Will it always be a rotated rectangle? And will you know the angle of rotation?

Comment: @andand It will always be the same exact shape. The rotated rectangle is the approximate boundary of a municipality. So it will never change.

Comment: If one of the answers solves your question, you might consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

A line equation of the form `ax+by+c==0` can be constructed from 2 points.  For a given point to be inside a convex shape, we need testing whether it lies on the same side of every line defined by the shape's edges.

In pure Python code, taking care of writing the equations avoiding divisions, this could be as follows:

```py
def is_on_right_side(x, y, xy0, xy1):
    x0, y0 = xy0
    x1, y1 = xy1
    a = float(y1 - y0)
    b = float(x0 - x1)
    c = - a*x0 - b*y0
    return a*x + b*y + c >= 0

def test_point(x, y, vertices):
    num_vert = len(vertices)
    is_right = [is_on_right_side(x, y, vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % num_vert]) for i in range(num_vert)]
    all_left = not any(is_right)
    all_right = all(is_right)
    return all_left or all_right

vertices = [(670273, 4879507), (677241, 4859302), (670388, 4856938), (663420, 4877144)]
```

The following plot tests the code visually for several shapes. Note that for shapes with horizontal and vertical lines usual line equations could provoke division by zero.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vertices1 = [(670273, 4879507), (677241, 4859302), (670388, 4856938), (663420, 4877144)]
vertices2 = [(680000, 4872000), (680000, 4879000), (690000, 4879000), (690000, 4872000)]
vertices3 = [(655000, 4857000), (655000, 4875000), (665000, 4857000)]
k = np.arange(6)
r = 8000
vertices4 = np.vstack([690000 + r * np.cos(k * 2 * np.pi / 6), 4863000 + r * np.sin(k * 2 * np.pi / 6)]).T
all_shapes = [vertices1, vertices2, vertices3, vertices4]

for vertices in all_shapes:
    plt.plot([x for x, y in vertices] + [vertices[0][0]], [y for x, y in vertices] + [vertices[0][1]], 'g-', lw=3)
for x, y in zip(np.random.randint(650000, 700000, 1000), np.random.randint(4855000, 4880000, 1000)):
    color = 'turquoise'
    for vertices in all_shapes:
        if test_point(x, y, vertices):
            color = 'tomato'
    plt.plot(x, y, '.', color=color)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: test plot]

PS: In case you are running a 32-bit version of numpy, with this size of integers it might be necessary to convert the values to float to avoid overflow.

If this calculation needs to happen very often, the `a,b,c` values can be precalculated and stored. If the direction of the edges is known, only one of `all_left` or `all_right` is needed.

When the shape is fixed, a text version of the function can be generated:

```py
def generate_test_function(vertices, is_clockwise=True, function_name='test_function'):
    ext_vert = list(vertices) + [vertices[0]]
    unequality_sign = '>=' if is_clockwise else '<='
    print(f'def {function_name}(x, y):')
    parts = []
    for (x0, y0), (x1, y1) in zip(ext_vert[:-1], ext_vert[1:]):
        a = float(y1 - y0)
        b = float(x0 - x1)
        c = a * x0 + b * y0
        parts.append(f'({a}*x + {b}*y {unequality_sign} {c})')
    print('    return', ' and '.join(parts))

vertices = [(670273, 4879507), (677241, 4859302), (670388, 4856938), (663420, 4877144)]
generate_test_function(vertices)
```

This would generate a function as:

```py
def test_function(x, y):
    return (-20205.0*x + -6968.0*y >= -47543270741.0) and (-2364.0*x + 6853.0*y >= 31699798882.0) and (20206.0*x + 6968.0*y >= 47389003912.0) and (2363.0*x + -6853.0*y >= -31855406372.0)
```

This function then can be copy-pasted and optimized by the Jython compiler. Note that the shape doesn't need to be rectangular. Any convex shape will do, allowing to use a tighter box.

Comment: How does this deal with the special case of a horizontal line?

Comment: @Blaine The equations are written in such a way that there are no divisions (and no slopes are calculated). That way they work for any orientation of the lines. Due to the `>=` it would even work when two successive points are equal, although that isn't recommended. It doesn't work well for concave shape though.

Comment: Thanks! I'm extremely green when it comes to Python. When I paste in your script, I get a syntax error. Would you happen to know why? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfG3r.png

Comment: Maybe your Python version doesn't know about the star syntax. I just adapted the code to work without it.

Answer (score 3):

Take three consequent vertices `A, B, C` (your 1,2,3)

Find lengths of sides `AB` and `BC`

```
lAB = sqrt((B.x - A.x)^2+(B.y - A.y)^2)
```

Get unit (normalized) direction vectors

```
uAB = ((B.x - A.x) / lAB, (B.y - A.y) / lAB)
```

For tested point `P` get vector `BP`

```
BP = ((P.x - B.x), (P.y - B.y))
```

And calculate signed distances from sides to point using cross product

```
SignedDistABP = Cross(BP, uAB) = BP.x * uAB.y - BP.y * uAB.x
SignedDistBCP = - Cross(BP, uBC) = - BP.x * uBC.y + BP.y * uBC.x
```

For points inside rectangle both distances should have the same sign - either negative or positive depending on vertices order (CW or CCW), and their absolute values should not be larger than `lBC` and `lAB` correspondingly

```
Abs(SignedDistABP) <= lBC
Abs(SignedDistBCP) <= lAB
```

Answer (score 2):

As the shape is an exact rectangle, the easiest is to rotate all points by the angle

```
-arctan((4859302-4856938)/(677241-670388))
```

Doing so, the rectangle becomes axis-aligned and you just have to perform four coordinate comparisons. Rotations are easy to compute with complex numbers.

---

In fact you can simply represent all points as complex numbers, compute the vector defined by some side, and multiply everything by the conjugate.

---

A slightly different approach is to consider the change of coordinate frame that brings some corner to the origin and two incident sides to (1,0) and (0,1). This is an affine transformation. Then your test boils down to checking insideness to the unit  square.

Comment: @User1973: mh, no, it is not that.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/248449/206844